# How can I reset permissions on (sub)folders under Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, permissions

I'm running Windows Vista, which is installed on my primary drive.

I have a second hard drive installed, which used to host my Windows XP install, and I'm trying to delete the Documents folder, but I don't have permissions to do so.

Is there a way I can reset the permissions on all subfolders of my second drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to "take ownership", here's a tutorial:

**[Add "Take Ownership" to Explorer Right-Click Menu in Win 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/)**