# Reset all permissions on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-management

I have an external hard drive and I did something which I shouldn't have done, and I am annoyed that many files are prompting me about Administrator permissions to move a folder.  They are regular files.

How do I reset all the permission on the external hard drive?

Comment: Do you just want to set all file permissions to something specific? When you say 'reset', I think of 'revert' - which I'm not sure is exactly what you want..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change permissions for the folder including subfolders?](http://superuser.com/questions/194365/how-can-i-change-permissions-for-the-folder-including-subfolders) and/or [How can I reset permissions on (sub)folders under Windows Vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/109116/how-can-i-reset-permissions-on-subfolders-under-windows-vista)

Comment: What would be considered not a regular file?

Comment: joeqwerty: thing that the OS depends on being there. Such as files in program/ or windows/. This is a extern HD for data files (audios, videos, backed up code, etc).@Doc: I do mean revert. I want any user to add/remove/move files like it was originally

Answer (score 11):

Run this command to navigate to the drive letter, example is `D`

```
D:
```

To reset all permissions, run this command

```
icacls * /reset /t /c /q
```

More info

```
/reset
    replaces ACLs with default inherited ACLs for all matching files.

/t indicates that this operation is performed on all matching
    files/directories below the directories specified in the name.

/c indicates that this operation will continue on all file errors.
    Error messages will still be displayed.

/q indicates that icacls should supress success messages.
```

[Resetting NTFS files security and permission in Windows 7](http://lallousx86.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/resetting-ntfs-files-security-and-permission-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

As answered in comments of this being a duplicate, use `cacls` with the subdirectory option to go through subfolders as well, with /G:Everyone. So the final command would be:
`CACLS x:\*.* /G:Everyone /T`

Comment: `cacls` is being deprecated, for vista or newer you should be using icacls. It adds new features like folder inheritance permissions.