# Can't install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 package

Tags: windows-10, dll

I'm trying to run a game (Train Simulator 2015) and I get a message saying that `MSVCR100.dll` is missing from my computer.

I googled it, and found that this is what I need : 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

I downloaded it, but when I try to install it, I get this error message :

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 redistributable has not been installed because: fatal error during installation

I have Windows 10 64-bits (the cheapest version). I tried running it as admin but it didn't help.

Is there anything else that I need to do/install before Visual C++ 2010?

**Edit** Error log on Pastebin : http://pastebin.com/jThJEqQT

Comment: There is a log that is generated you need to supply it.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the fast reply, I've updated my post.

Comment: This error is caused by a permission problem.  Reset your ACLs on your installation.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I do this?

Comment: here is how...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d09a393b-68df-43de-9f31-735f83242497/quick-way-to-reset-all-security-permissions-to-default-windows-7?forum=w7itprosecurity

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/321070/reset-all-permissions-on-windows-7/321099#321099) this fixes the permissions on the required directories